# CSV import stopped working when I upgraded to WP 3.5.2

Tags: csv

I used to import Greek text in posts using various plug-ins such as CSV improter.

All these stopped working once I upgraded WP to 3.5.2

Any known issues?

Thanks.

Comment: **All** of your importing plugins stopped working? At a first glance, the only change that could affect this [is in the SWFUploader](http://wordpress.org/news/2013/06/wordpress-3-5-2/). Do a full [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) and add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your Question.

Comment: Thanks but this is quite complex, maybe someone else encountered this?

Comment: What is "quite complex"? Your site configuration or troubleshooting/debugging?